# CORS no Acess-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, html, xml, cors

In my Javascript file I want to load xml data from this site: https://www.anime2you.de/feed/

But I always get a no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header despite using CORS. Did I misunderstand the concept / usage of CORS or is the website faulty?

My code:

```
var feeds = ["https://www.anime2you.de/feed/"];

var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
   // Most browsers.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
   } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
     // IE8 & IE9
       xhr = new XDomainRequest();
       xhr.open(method, url);
   } else {
     // CORS not supported.
       xhr = null;
   }
 return xhr;
};

var url = 'https://www.anime2you.de/feed/';
var method = 'GET';
var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

xhr.onload = function() {
  alert("success");
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert("fail");
};

xhr.send();
```

Thanks in advance
Nova

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); on the script you are requesting? https://www.anime2you.de/feed/ if you are using Access-Control-Allow-Origin with a wildcard then set the credentials to false in

```
xhr.withCredentials = false;
```

If you can set the domain name of the server making the request i.e

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain-where-js-sits");
```

then you can do:

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

and set these other headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

An alternative is to use jsonp - this may not work for you as the response needs to be in json:

```
function response(data) {
    edit the returned data here
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://www.anime2you.de/feed/?callback-response';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Could you please explain how to set the header? Because I thought header(...) is php

Comment: If you are not using php on: https://www.anime2you.de/feed/ you will need to find away some where on the server maybe a .htaccess file or the apache config file depending what your server is running. In IIS if its windows.

Comment: The server isn't mine. It is a page containing the Rss feed of a website. I want to get the xml data to display the feed on my website. I have no control over anime2you

Comment: added an alternative solution using jsonp.  however this may not work if https://www.anime2you.de/feed/ cannot return json. Failing this you would have to think about using an iframe although I know the data will not be correctly formatted. Can you not use server side code rather than javascript? Then you could do a http request to https://www.anime2you.de/feed/ and format the response to your hearts content

Comment: The problem is that I don't know php at all. But I could use Node. Js.

Comment: maybe this will help then: https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser quick google search for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'll be able to do the rest myself.